# Cypress: user agent is picked up correctly, but logic tied to it not triggering

Tags: reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, user-agent

**Objective**:

- check `navigator.userAgent`
- do a simple UI change based on userAgent

**Findings**:

the logic works as intended on:

- real iOS device
- chrome emulator
- firefox emulator

| chrome | firefox | cypress (PROBLEM) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Chrome works as intended] | [image: firefox] | [image: cypress-problem] |

**Problem**:

- in cypress, even though `navigator.userAgent` is correct, UI logic is not triggered

[COMPLETE PROJECT REPO HERE](https://github.com/AkberIqbal/cypress-user-agent/tree/main/cypress-user-agent)

relevant code for using userAgent inside cypress:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    userAgent:
      "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
  },
});
```

code for UI logic:

```
const isiOSDevice = () =>
  navigator.vendor === "Apple Computer, Inc." ||
  (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
    !window.MSStream &&
    "ontouchend" in document);

function App() {
  const isIOS = isiOSDevice();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <div className={`ios-${isIOS}`}>
          <p>
            are we on iOS device? <code>{isIOS.toString()}</code>
            <br /> navigator.userAgent is: {navigator.userAgent}
          </p>
          {isIOS ? (
            <p>
              hence we would see <span>blue</span> color
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p>
              hence we would see <span>red</span> color
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, appreciate a reproducible repo to help out on this question.

The issue is in your `isiOSDevice()` primarily the `"ontouchend" in document`, which returns `undefined` for Canary, Chrome, Electron, and Firefox.

I removed that part of the logic on local and was able to get iOS device as true and blue. Also, added console logging of the values as proof.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of testing for `touchend` I use `navigator.maxTouchPoints`, but I can't say it's definitive either way. I have a WinOS & touch screen.

```js
const isiOSDevice = () =>
  navigator.vendor === "Apple Computer, Inc." ||
  (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) &&
    !window.MSStream &&
    navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1)
```